# Receipt Printer vertical limit browser

Tags: javascript, php, browser, printing, receipt

Is there a way to set a vertical limit to a receipt printer. If I print a screen form browser to print it doesn't know the vertical limit and prints nonstop. I am developing a system with PHP and Javascript, so if any code can help it would also be nice.
I know that this is not the correct way to print in this kind of printer, but it would be easy.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a print stylesheet (CSS)?  You can set up the page geometry there. Print style support is generally terrible in browsers but you can usually rely on that.

Comment: What would be a print stylesheet, could you give me a sample? Would it be something like in this link https://www.seehuhn.de/pages/cssgeom.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing

Answer (score 0):

Removing the header and footer solves the problem. I did this automatically by adding the below code.

```
 <style type="text/css">
        @page 
        {
            size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
            margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        }
    </style>
```